# How to stop elements moving position when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to web developing so forgive me if this has been answered before but I have had a look and didn't find anything I can relate to my code.

I have 3 images that are displayed inline and when hovering I want that specific image to increase in size with the other 2 images remaining where they are. The issue I'm having is that when I hover and the image increases in size, the other two images move around. I've tried changing the `position` property to `absolute`and `relative` but neither has worked.

For reference here is the source code: https://codepen.io/jacobc1596/pen/mdbWyqm

Or if it's easier to see it displayed here, the CSS code is:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px
}

h2 {
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  border-radius:30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}


.topnav a.active {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: #000;
}

#logo {
  float:left;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#contact {
  border: 2px solid;
}

#contact:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#studio {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius:45%;
}

#studio:hover {
  width:525px;
  height:525px;
}

#services {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:30px;
  filter: grayscale(100%); 
}

#services:hover {
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}

.images {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.images a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:30px;
}

.images a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

figure {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The HTML code is (image links changed for brevity):

```
<div class="topnav">  
  <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="logo" href="#">tone-o productions</a>
</div>

<div class="images">
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="image URL here"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Graphics</a></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="image URL here" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Production</a></figcaption>  
</figure>

<figure>
<a href="#"><img id="services" src="image URL here" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Videography</a></figcaption>
</figure> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks great!

The reason for the jump is you're changing the width and height of the images on hover which is pushing everything around. Instead, use transform and scale instead of messing with absolute positioning.

It won't be pixel perfect but that shouldn't matter.

```css
.images {
  display: flex
}

figure img {
   transition: transform 250ms ease-out
}

figure:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: center
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="//placehold.it/128x128"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Graphics</a></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="//placehold.it/128x128" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Production</a></figcaption>  
</figure>

<figure>
<a href="#"><img id="services" src="//placehold.it/128x128" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Videography</a></figcaption>
</figure> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the margins when you make the images bigger so that they don't push any other items around.  The images increase in size by 50px, so you should decrease the margins by 25px.  Add the line `margin:5px;` to your hovered image style:

```
#services:hover {
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
   <div class="topnav">  
  <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="logo" href="#">tone-o productions</a>
</div>

<div class="images">
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="https://instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e06330d5a57920dc42271cfdfbf7ee31/5E0D37DE/t51.2885-15/e35/29738767_156304275196682_9010195359502172160_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net" alt= "pic1"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Graphics</a></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="#"><img id="services" src="https://instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5e98b9dfbeb3d92297ab180e45731468/5DFABE94/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s750x750/27880184_580447755636489_3066552335187574784_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Production</a></figcaption>  
</figure>

<figure>
<a href="#"><img id="services" src="https://instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/227d1000d16dd864752896c0ce4653c7/5DD93912/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s750x750/42429044_495556827588508_8753915026181074890_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flhr3-2.fna.fbcdn.net" alt="pic2"></a>
  <figcaption><a href="#">Videography</a></figcaption>
</figure> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px
}

h2 {
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/*to style the links in the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  border-radius:30px;
}
/* change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
/* add color to the active/current link*/
.topnav a.active {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: #000;
}
#logo {
  float:left;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#contact {
  border: 2px solid;
}
#contact:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#studio {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius:45%;
}

#studio:hover {
  width:525px;
  height:525px;

}

#services {
  width:70%;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  //margin:30px;
  filter: grayscale(100%); 
}

#services:hover {
  width:75%;
  height:350px;
}

.images {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

.images a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Righteous, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:30px;
}

.images a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

figure {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  margin:0px;
}
```